# BPMN optional support for a task from a different lane

Tags: bpmn

I have a lane that if needed can get consulting for a task from a different lane. Is there a good way to connect the two?

[basic overview with missing connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp1U5.png)

Comment: Do you need the link toward a single task or for any task in the above lane?

Comment: @DavideCalarco The consulting should be possible for multiple tasks in the upper lane

Answer (score 0):

The problem is defining a callable process like consult, since it may be invoked by multiple tasks.

Just define the consult process globally. Then, for each task that may require it, prepend a call activity that calls the global consult process. Notice that the consult process may do nothing to model optionality.

[image: Consult global process]

For each call activity, set the called element to point to the consult global process.
For instance, in XML, you can call the global process by adding the attribute calledElement to the call activity, having as value the id of the global process.

Comment: Thanks looks good but doesn't yet allow for consulting during the 'checking' if that is even possible.